# Deixar imagem com texto responsivo

Tags: jquery, html5, imagem, bootstrap, layout-responsivo

Olá,

estou precisando inserir um texto em cima de uma imagem, que seja responsivo no lugar correto da imagem, até ai está funcionando "bem", porem  o site é feito em bootstrap, e quando ele sai do col-md-4 e vai para o tamanho col-xs-12 (quando redimensiona a janela). A partir dai o texto fica pequeno de mais.

O que eu quero é que o texto se adapte a imagem, assim como a imagem se adapta ao redimensionamento da janela.

Segue o jsfiddle com exemplo:
https://jsfiddle.net/xuavhmg7/2/

O código peguei desse site:
http://alt-web.com/TUTORIALS/?id=responsive_text_overlays

Editado:
David Samm me ajudou muito.

JsFidlle Atualizado: https://jsfiddle.net/xuavhmg7/3/

Ficou com um delay ao trocar, mas aceitável. Talvez se eu colocar 'else if' par todos ['xs','sm','md','lg'] com valores diferentes de 'font-size' suavize a troca.

Adicionei esse script para pegar o breakpoint do bootstrap3.

```
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/maciej-gurban/responsive-bootstrap-toolkit/master/dist/bootstrap-toolkit.min.js"></script>
```

E fiz essa função para mudar os valores.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($, document, window, viewport){
      function setTextSize() {
        if ((viewport.current() == 'xs') || (viewport.current() == 'sm')) {
          $("figure.overlay figcaption").css('font-size','7.0vw');
        } else {
          $("figure.overlay figcaption").css('font-size','2.4vw');
        }
      }

      // Executes once whole document has been loaded
      $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('Current breakpoint:', viewport.current());
        setTextSize();
      });

      $(window).resize(
        viewport.changed(function(){
          console.log('Current breakpoint:', viewport.current());
          setTextSize();
        })
      );
    })(jQuery, document, window, ResponsiveBootstrapToolkit);

  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entendo quase nada de Bootstrap, mas conheço um recurso em jQuery que irá forçar o tamanho da fonte em questão. Adicione o código abaixo na sua página:

```
<script>
$(window).on('load resize',function(){
    if($(window).width() < 992){
        $("figure.overlay figcaption").css('font-size','7.3vw');
    }else{
        $("figure.overlay figcaption").css('font-size','2.0vw');    
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Muito boa a resposta, me ajudou a refazer o código. Editei minha postagem com dados adicionais. E está funcionando.